# Storing a password hash where the password length can only be 30 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have a `Person` class what contains a password field like this:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Password must be between 6 and 30 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

I need to store the hash of this password in the database, except if I change the password value to be a hash of itself then it triggers the validation and throws a `DbEntityValidationException` because it is longer than 30 characters.

I know I could not constrain the length and I would love to do that but it is one of the requirements which I have no say over.

I have tried this:

```
private string _Password;
public string Password { get { return _Password } set { _Password = PasswordHasher.HashPassword(value) } }
```

But this triggers the exception.

How could I get the hash to store in the database?

Comment: You need to validate & hash the password outside the EF layer.

Comment: You need to separate your domain model from the view model. The view model `Password` property has the `[StringLength]` attribute, but the domain model does not.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. This is my first time using Entity :/

Comment: Have a look at the code in the `AccountController` (and the associated models) when you generate a new project using Visual Studio.